# Can i create class objects with a class that just offers a copy constructor?

Tags: c++, nullptr, default-copy-constructor

Is it possible to create instances of a class that only offers a copy-ctor?
Or is it good design to also delete a copy-ctor, if one deletes all other ctors?

```
struct EmptyClass
{
    EmptyClass() = delete;

    // using compiler generated copy ctor.    

    // empty class, also nothing virtual.

    void fn()
    {
    }
};


int main()
{
    {
        const EmptyClass obj(*static_cast<const EmptyClass*>(nullptr));
        obj.fn();
    }

    // or

    {
        char buffer[sizeof EmptyClass]{};
        const EmptyClass obj(*reinterpret_cast<const EmptyClass*>(buffer);
        obj.fn();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Whats the point? Do you want a namespace? Both your examples in your `main()` are undefined behaviour and won't result in a valid object of type `EmptyClass`.

Comment: Swordfish, thanx. That's (UB) what i wanted to hear.

Comment: I don't see why you would want this. So it's possible to create an object of the type, but only in bizarre and difficult ways?

Comment: @Swordfish Are you sure? Is dereferencing an invalidly aliased pointer itself UB, or only using that false object? Because it would seem the copy constructor might not actually use it.

Comment: My question... Can somebody abuse a class, if i allow copy-construction?

class Obj
{
 Obj() = delete;
};


So, should i write always like this and also forbid copy-ctor?


class Obj
{
 Obj() = delete;
 Obj(const Obj&) = delete;
};

Comment: Okay, I see [expr.unary.op]/3 saying the result of unary `*` is "the object or function to which the expression points" - which doesn't exactly address what sort of mistake this is, but clearly requires a pointer to an actual object or function.

Comment: 1st is dereferencing a `nullptr`, 2nd needs a `reinterpret_cast<>` and is illegal aliasing. If it were allowed: allignment requirements? There is no object of type `EmptyClass` in `buffer`. Pretending won't help ^^

Comment: @bergauffahrer The bigger question is what are you trying to prevent and why?

Comment: @Swordfish: changed to reinterpret_cast, thanks.

Comment: @Rotem: will answer that soon...

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to create instances of an object *de novo* if the object's only accessible non-deleted constructors are copy and move constructors, with one exception: the object may support aggregate initialization. In your case, `EmptyClass` is an aggregate so I can do this:

```
EmptyClass c{};  // doesn't call the default constructor
```

In order to prevent this, we must first declare the default constructor and *then* define it as deleted:

```
struct EmptyClass {
    EmptyClass();
};
EmptyClass::EmptyClass() = delete;
```

This makes `EmptyClass` not an aggregate. In this case, it will be impossible to create objects of this type.